In-App & Web - Status not changing to Inactive after Set Time in Messaging Settings
I am trying to implement Messaging for In-App and Web solutions for one of our requirements. To mark the chats as Inactive I have done the required configuration as given on this link. But even after this the conversation status is not changing to Inactive but remains active. After the time set in messaging settings the automatic message is delivered to customers that this chat will be marked as inactive now but the conversation remains active and a customer is still able to send message. Even if agent tries to mark the conversation as inactive through std. button present on conversation as described here the chat remains active. I am not able to figure out whats going wrong here. If anybody has implemented this can you pls let me know if I am missing something here? Or if there's any permission that needs to be given to customer/agent to let them change the status of chat. Any help is appreciated!

I understand your confusion. After the timeout you configured in "Automatically Mark Messaging Sessions Inactive", the status of the MessagingSession record session will change to Inactive, but the customer’s session will not be ended link.

The key point is that the MessagingSession is not terminated. If the customer types something again, the session status will update to Waiting and will attempt to assign an agent.
On the other hand, if the Messaging Session remains in the Inactive status for approximately 24 hours, it will be permanently marked as inactive. In this case, if the customer sends a new message, a new messaging session will be created.
When an agent clicks “End Chat,” if the community user types something again, a new MessagingSession will be created. However, the agent will still see the old chat within the new MessagingSession (here I might be incorrect because I am using the configuration below.).

One useful note: if you need to display a pre-chat form after the session has been ended by Agent, you can configure this setting as follows:
Setup → Embedded Service Deployment → Edit Pre-Chat → Pre-Chat Display Frequency: "Every Session" link.



Thanks Andrii. Actually the issue was with permissions for agents. They were missing the edit access for Status field on messaging session. Once given, I could see the status was changing to inactive. But still after that if customer sends a message I don't how does the re-routing work because I have not seen where exactly to configure that. Not sure if it falls back to the fallback queue defined on messaging channel setting. Do you have any idea about that?

You are absolutely correct! First, check the “Routing Type” in Setup > Messaging Settings configurations. This should provide clarity on how routing is being handled in your case.
If the Routing Type is set to “Omni-Flow”, you can verify the Flow Interviews to ensure that the Omni-Flow did not fail and that routing occurred correctly.
You can also review the routing flow to understand the logic behind how routing is configured and executed.
